# Export metrics to console with Spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How can I export metrics to console or log with Spring Boot Actuator, is a requirement, I can't use Redis or something similar.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure what are you asking

Comment: WIth Spring Boot actuator you can exports metrics to Redis, for example, I would like export metrics to Console (with Logger) every 30 seconds, instead of Redis. But I did not get it. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I see, you need implement the MetricWriter, which has a static logger, then you can write to console with your log... solution is pretty straight forward..but you cannot really easily count them or find them... you need to see this, have a look at MetricsReader

Comment: The Dropwizard metrics integration for spring-boot also has an exporter that will write to the logs.

Comment: yes, you are right cjstehno, thank you